# How can I access the 'Action' field in django-simple-history?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-simple-history

I'm using `django-simple-history` to record changes in my models. I cannot find a way to access the "Action" in the history model.

DATE/TIME   USER    ACTION

```
invoice.history_date 
invoice.history_user
invoice. ____ ?
```

I have not found a working solution. I have tried: `invoice.action`, `invoice.actions`, `invoice.history_action/s`, etc. and they don't work. I want to show what exactly was changed.